# Cournot competition: profit maximizer vs. market share maximizer

Tags: game-theory, economics

Today during an informal conversation with an established business researcher, I learned such a fact:

> In the classical Cournot competition model, if one player is a
>   profit-maximizer, the other is a market-share-maximizer, then in
>   equilibrium the market-share-maximizer actually earns a higher profit
>   than the profit-maximizer.

I find this statement quite counterintuitive, so I attempted showing it by myself, to little avail.

The following is what I tried with the basic Cournot model:

There are two competing firms. Let price (demand) be $P(q)=a-q$ for some constant $a$, where $q$ is the total quantity equal to $q_1+q_2$, the sum of the quantities of the two firms respectively. Then profit of firm $i$ is $\pi_i=q_i(P(q_1+q_2)-c)$ where $c$ is the constant unit cost.

Assume firm $1$ maximizes profit: $$ \frac{\partial \pi_1}{\partial q_1}=P(q_1+q_2)-c-q_1=a-2q_1-q_2-c. \tag{1}$$

Firm $2$ maximizes market share $\frac{q_2}{q_1+q_2}$: $$\frac{\partial \left(\frac{q_2}{q_1+q_2}\right)}{\partial q_2}=\frac{q_1+q_2-q_2}{(q_1+q_2)^2}=\frac{q_1}{(q_1+q_2)^2}>0 $$ as long as $q_1>0$. So firm $2$'s best response is its whole capacity whenever firm $1$ produces a positive amount. It is reasonable to assume that firm $2$ wouldn't produce so much to drive the equilibrium price to below its cost $c$ (when it would make a loss); in this case, $q_2^*=a-q_1-c$.

Setting $(1)=0$ we get $a-2q_1^*-(a-q_1^*-c)-c=0$, or $q_1^*=0$. Hence both firms make zero profits. Indeed, the market-share-maximizer earns no less profit than the profit maximizer, but this result is rather trivial and I don't think it is what this researcher meant.

Did I miss something here? It is completely possible that I misinterpreted what this researcher meant during the conversation. So my question is, if everything I've derived here is correct, is there some other interpretation or variant of the "fact" I quoted that is actually true and interesting? Or is there a related similar result that is true and interesting?

Comment: Concerning the notation only. It should be $P(q_1,q_2)$ instead of P$(q_1+q_2)$

Comment: @calculus I actually meant $P(q_1+q_2)$. In the classical Cournot competition setting, the quantities of the two firms are added to obtain the total quantity, from which the equilibrium price is obtained. This is a model assumption. More information can be found [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cournot_competition)

Comment: This result also seems for me counter-intuitive. Nevertheless, it might be that under certain conditions such a result can be derived. The example you presented is only a counter example under the strictly larger case, however, for the weaker case it is not a disproof. Therefore, I propose to have a look at the reference and to study the proof. Check it, and do not forget to impose a logical cross-check on the arguments. Even some peer-reviewed articles have severe logical deficiencies.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt The difficulty is that I don't think this result this scholar mentioned is documented anywhere that's publicly accessible. He just mentioned it on the fly.

Comment: In this case, the statement has no theoretical foundation. For the classical Cournot case such a result can not be derived. However, in business the market share is an objective for some firms, and these people need some justification for their actions. In this respect, the only reference I found that captures somehow this point is given here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167718706000853

Comment: It's just a guess, but maybe try adding fixed costs to the model and impose a non-negative profit condition.

Comment: @tadejsv It might work, if you imposes some fixed costs or a strictly increasing cost function (some kind of supermodularity is certainly required) to the profit maximizer and constant cost to the market share optimizer. Probably, you also need to impose some additional restrictions on the revenue functions to get the desired best reply functions that assure the existence of an equilibrium. But this has nothing to do with a classical Cournot setting.

Comment: Well I haven't computed this model, but just the imposition of non-negative profits alone here I think could be sufficient to achieve a Nash equilibrium, as it would give you a best-reponse function of the share-maximizing firm, which is now absent it the quantitiy produced of the other firm is not 0.

Comment: @tadejsv For an unique Nash equilibrium, a firm enters with fixed costs a market if the return on investment is positive. In a deterministic economy, a decision maker realizes in advance if this condition is satisfied. For multiple equilibria, a firm enters a market, if the expected profit is positive. If a bad equilibrium occurs a firm stays in the market as long as it can cover its variable costs (fixed costs are sunk). Imposing non-negative profits cut off the best-responses and the equilibria set. This implies that the game model is not fully described.

Comment: Em no, because in the case of a share maximizing firm without non negative profits you have no best response function, as whatever the production of the other firm (if not 0), the firm can always achieve a better pay-off (a bigger market share) by producing more, so a best response function would be "infinty", but this just means that every quantity is dominated by an even bigger one. If you impose the non-negative profits condition, a best reponse is the biggest quantity, at which the profit is 0.

Comment: @tadejsv If I follow your argument, the imposition of non-negative profits ensure an oligopoly market with two types. In contrast, if this assumption is dropped, the market share maximizer gets the whole market. In my opinion, it is sufficient to impose a market quantity that drives the profit maximizer out of the market, that is, to its shut-down condition. An infinite quantity is certainly not required. But then we have an oligopoly market with only one type, or even a monopoly. This would contradict the initial statement. A profit maximizer will not enter such a market.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your colleague meant that the market share maximizer also take into account marginal cost, which you had omitted in the above model. In my opinion, if one substitutes market shares instead quantities in the model, result do not change. The reason is that market shares are measures that are based in the quantities traded so, in fact, these are only a linear reparametrization.